# Loop sequentialy object

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, for-loop, iqueryable

I have a `IQueryable` object q of questions.

```
  DataClasses1DataContext dc = new DataClasses1DataContext();
        var q = from a in dc.GetTable<Questions>()
                select a ;
```

In question i have `questionId` and `question`.

[image]
How can i loop through `IQueryable` data sequentially based on the next `button click event` so that i have the first question text as `Lebel.Text` and in my `DropDown` answers based on `questionId`, then after click next question i go to second question from `IQueryable` and continue like this until finish al questions?

Answer (score 2):

```
var enumerator = q.AsEnumerable().GetEnumerator();

In event handler:

if(enumerator.MoveNext())
{
      var question = enumerator.Current;
}
```

Comment: `Current` is property, not method. Just in case.

Answer (score 0):

```
ctor()
{
    DataClasses1DataContext dc = new DataClasses1DataContext();
    var q = from a in dc.GetTable<Questions>()
            select a;
    _questionEnumerator = q.GetEnumerator();
}

void btn_click(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    if (_questionEnumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        var row = _questionEnumerator.Current;
        // do stuff
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, it is a bad practice to use directly the `Enumerator`.

If you need to get the questions on-the-fly, make a database request each time user presses the button:

```
Question question;

using (dataContext = new DataClasses1DataContext())
    question = dataContext.GetTable<Questions>().Skip(questionIndex).First();
```

If you need **can** hold all the questions in memory, just project them all to your application's memory:

```
IList<Question> questions;

using (dataContext = new DataClasses1DataContext())
    questions = dataContext.GetTable<Questions>().ToList();
```

Also, it is a bad pracite to keep the SQL (or any other database) connection keep-alive more than its needed. There are dozens of reasons, one of the most popular is that table while reading inside the default C# transaction implementation can hold a lock on that table, rendering it unable to process other requests.